# Angularjs with chrome app

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-app

I am working with angularjs. I need to create a chrome app with angular, but it does not load the `angular.min.js` files. Also, can I call a function with angularjs on chrome app. (Normally it is not possible calling a function in chrome app, other than using `addEventLsitener`)

Comment: sound interesting.. are you willing to host the code somewhere ? may be on github.

Comment: See https://github.com/sowbug/happynine

Answer (score 1):

You are not very clear, so I'll guess that angular is not working in your chrome app.
This is because angular makes uses of eval() which chrome apps won't allow see @ [csp](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy).

If you are using angular make sure that you have ng-csp enable e.g. `<html lang="en" ng-csp ng-app='appname'>`
In order to call a function in angular you would need to do it the old wait via click,blur,focus, etc... events. Angular has replaced then with [ngClick](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick), ngBlur, ngFocus, etc... 
`<button type='button' name='name' ng-click='functionName()'>DoSomething</button>`. 
The function has to exist in your scope as well.